# How to download a file from a url in a public folder of React.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to download a file from a url in a public folder of React.js project.

I have tried by anchor  tag download option and some more like fetch, axios etc but not able to download in public folder of react project from a image url link.

Comment: Add the code that you tried. A file inside the public folder is going to be inside the website itself so don't include the `public` word in the url

Comment: I have tried that codes are normal for just download a file but don’t know how to download in a folder of the website itself

Comment: ok, I still have no idea what you tried.

Comment: Can you share what code you have to download in website folder a file form url?

Comment: You can copy and paste the url of the file you want to download into any browser and it will download it. Or you can make a GET request. You could also use a tool like Wget.